# Did the dollar depreciate when Trump won the election?

Tags: international-trade, exchange-rates, international-economics

I expected the the dollar to briefly depreciate against all currencies when Trump won the election (in 2016), but I have just learned that it briefly appreciated against some. It depreciated against the Euro and Pound, but appreciated against the South African Rand and Australian Dollar. Why did the Rand and AUD depreciate against the dollar?

[image]
[Source](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=ZAR&to=USD&view=1M)
[image]
[Source](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=AUD&to=USD&view=1M)
[image]
[Source](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=EUR&to=USD&view=1M)

Comment: I edited your question to provide some context. It seems that the spikes in the non-euro exchange rates are relatively smaller, i.e. these are more volatile currencies. But there are clear spikes, and they do go in the opposite direction as the EUR to USD spike does. If you disagree with the edit, roll it back.